# How to apply multiple filter while pulling utilization data for CosmosDB using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-monitor

I am using Get-AzMetric to pull data from azure monitor and New-AzMetricFilter to apply filter in Get-AzMetric.

Code:

```
$dimFilter = @((New-AzMetricFilter -Dimension CollectionName -Operator eq -Value $collectionName), (New-AzMetricFilter -Dimension Region -Operator eq -Value 'Central US'))
$output = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $resourceid  -StartTime $startTime -EndTime $endTime -MetricNames $metricsName -TimeGrain $timeGrain -MetricFilter $dimFilter -AggregationType Average
```

I am using above code but I am getting an error saying bad request.
How can I apply multiple filter at once in Get-Azmetrics.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I also received the same **"bad request error"** when I tried in my environment previously. After explored regarding this, I found a way to resolve it as follows:

If any parameter in `Get-Azmetric` is not correctly given then it will throw bad request error. So, here `-Metricfilter` is throwing an issue why because if you are creating multiple dimensions with `New-AzMetricFilter` command and storing it in a variable called `$dimfilter`.

Then the type of this variable will be `system.array` (object type). `-MetricFilter` only supports string type. There is a need to convert it into `string` type first and pass it into a `foreach` loop. Then it will retrieve all the required metric results with the metric filter dimensions.

***To know the type of the stored variable use below:***

```
$dimFilter.Gettype()
```

[image]

***I've tried to obtain a metrics for a `storage account` and it worked for me.***

*Created* `metricfilters` *as yours:*

```
$dimFilter = @((New-AzMetricFilter -Dimension APIname -Operator eq -Value "GetBlob" ), (New-AzMetricFilter -Dimension Authentication -Operator eq -Value AccountKey))
```

***Converted to*** `[system.string]` ***initially***:

```
[system.String]::Join(" ",$dimfilter)
```

***I used a `foreach` loop to traverse the `array` objects and it gave me expected outcome.***

```
foreach($filter in $dimfilter){      
 Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroup>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storageaccountname>" -MetricName "Availability" -MetricFilter $filter
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: If you will put filter in for each loop then it will apply filter one by one right . then you will get data for separate filter. Basically i want to pull data using both filter at once.

Comment: In that case, store these two filters' data in an array and run `get-azmetric` with the obtained result filter.

Comment: array solution is not working i tried that